# Bug tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Why does two top appear and root becomes visible even though I have hidden it?

it started to happen when I decided to scatter all the functions into separate modules

```
from tkinter import *
import commands
root = Tk()  # Создаем основное окно
top = Toplevel()  # Создаем окно для выбора сложности
# добавляем виджеты в окно выбора сложности
var = IntVar()
Radiobutton(top, text='Легкая', variable=var, value=0).pack()
Radiobutton(top, text='Нормальная', variable=var, value=1).pack()
Radiobutton(top, text='Сложная', variable=var, value=2).pack()
button1 = Button(top, text="Играть", command=lambda: commands.command()).pack()
button2 = Button(top, text="Выйти", command=lambda: commands.command2()).pack()


def start_app():
    root.withdraw()  # Скрываем основное окно, пока показываем окно выбора сложности
    return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = start_app()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run your code, I can only see 1 window. Also are you importing this file? If you are then `app = start_app()` will never run.

Answer (score 0):

Normally creating a `Toplevel` window without specifying a parent would cause `tkinter` to create one, but since one ( the root ) has already been created this does not occur.

So only one `Tk` and one `Toplevel` exists.

Here is proof.

```py
from tkinter import *

# create parent window
root = Tk()  # Создаем основное окно
root.title('I am Parent')

top = Toplevel()  # Создаем окно для выбора сложности
top.title('I am Top')

# find parent of top
master = top.master

print('master equals root? {}'.format( master == root ))
```